# How can I create a circular query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

What I what is a query with offset and limit of one, that when the offset is bigger than the count it returns the first one.

For example: if I have a collecton with 3 elements and I do a query with offset = 4 I will get the first element. Any idea of how to implement this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish/why do you need this? Maybe there's another way to accomplish the same goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a count() first and if the number is less than your offset do a findOne?

Comment: I could do it but I want to avoid doing two operations. I also can't store it cause I am in a transient object.

Comment: I don't think there's a nice way of doing that with a single query.  Are you always just wanting one item?  what about a query with a reverse sort and a findOne()?

Comment: Yes, I always want one item. The desired effect is a circular structure, I don't think that just reverse sort can do it.

Comment: Maybe I don't understood, can you give an example?

Comment: db.collection.find({...}).sort(someField : -1).limit(1)

so you reverse the order then take only the first (which is really the last) one.

Comment: What I want is not to get the last element, I want a cricular list behaviour. For example: if I query for the 5 element in a list of 3, I want the 2 element.

Comment: Yeah.  that's not going to happen in one query.

Comment: So I will stay with the count. Thanks.